# use specific field as a backbone's model data

Tags: parsing, backbone.js, fetch

I'm retrieving a json and want to use a field(don't know the right term) in the json to initialize backbone model after fetch.

It seems I have to implement `parse` function, but how?

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to define `defaults` object on your model setting up properties you want to populate from a request; 2) then you need to filter (those) necessary fields and construct new object in the model's `parse` method:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        swordType: null
    },
    parse: function(data) {
        // filter what you need
        var swordTypeValue = null;
        if(data.hasOwnProperty('swordType')) {
            swordTypeValue = data.swordType;
        }
        // construct attributes from it
        return { swordType: swordTypeValue };
    }
});
```